# How To Get Sum Of Value Field in Associated Document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have two Mongoose models: User and one for Activity associated with them

User Schema

```
let userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    clan: { type: String },
    activities: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Activity',
    }],
});
```

Activity Schema

```
let activitySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String },
    point: { type: Number },
});
```

So the data is something like this

```
[{
    name: "Player A",
    clan: "Some Clan",
    activities: [{
         name: "Wake up",
         point: 5
    },{
         name: "Eat,
         point: 3
    }]
},{
    name: "Player B",
    clan: "Some Clan",
    activities: [{
         name: "Wake up",
         point: 5
    },{
         name: "Sleep",
         point: 5
    }]
}]
```

now, how i sum all the players points where the player is in clan "Some Clan"?

I'm expecting result like this

```
{
     sumOfPoints: 18 // because sum of player activities in "Some Clan" is 5 + 3 + 5 + 5
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Form Query like this:

```
db.user.aggregate({$match:{clan:"Clan A"}},
    {$unwind: {path:"$activity"}},
    {$lookup:{from: "activityCollection", localField: "activity._id", foreignField:"_id", as:"activityData"}},
    {$unwind: {path: "$activityData" }},
    {$group:{
        _id:"$_id", 
        name: {$first: "$name"},
        clan: {$first: "$clan"},
        totalPoints:{$sum:"$activityData.points"}
    }}).pretty()
```

**Explanation:**

First I used **`$unwind`** on the `activity` field from `users` collection as it is an array and we want to perform **`$lookup`** with _id field from activity array.

after performing `$lookup`, I used `$unwind` on lookup result,

and in **`$group stage`**, used **`$sum accumulator`** to add the points.

Hope this helps you find the answer.